# OpenVPN can connect but can not ping any server and internet traffic fails

Tags: windows, networking, openvpn

So this is a weird one. I have dozens of OpenVPN servers hosted on a pfsense server 2.4. I recently ran into a problem where the a single client can connect but can not ping the router or the openvpn gateway. Other users in his office do not suffer the same issue. This client has gone as far as to reset his windows 10 pc with the same results.

I have used tcpdump to monitor the traffic from his allocated ip address and there is nothing going across the openvpn client. He can ping google.com but he can not ping 8.8.8.8.

Edit:
As has been stated in the comments pinging google.com returns an ipv6 address. I have tried turning ipv6 networking off in windows 10 to no success. I do agree that communication apears to be going across ipv6

Since this first client brought the issue to my attention I have found another client with the same issue. The only consistent thing between the 2 clients is they are both using Comcast Business. One is on the east coast and the other on the west coast both in metropolitan areas. In an attempt to see if things were working I used iplocation.net to see if the location changed. When connected to OpenVPN the ipv4 address does not load but does load when disconnected from the VPN.

Comment: Have you checked for duplicate network prefixes, messing up the routing?

Comment: Does `ping google.com` return ipv4 address or ipv6?  I may be wrong but it seems like that there is no ipv4 communication.

Comment: google.com returns a ipv6 address. I agree with you but I don' know why or how.